# ERROR: tasks is not a legal parameter - Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I have a conditional include statement to include a task:

```
  tasks:
    # Install Java if not present
  - name: Execute Java
    shell: java -version
    register: result
    ignore_errors: True

  - include: tasks/java.yml
    when: result | failed
    ...
```

When I execute playbook it give out an error:

```
user1@localhost:~ ansible-playbook tomcat.yml
ERROR: tasks is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

However when I replace this `include` statement with `shell` or something else, playbook runs as expected....
[Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-and-includes) tells that task can be conditionally included, so why I am getting error here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solution:** You should leave out the "tasks:" part in the included file.

**Why it fails:**
When you include, you are already in the *tasks* section so to Ansible it looks like:

```
- tasks:
    tasks:
      - name: https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the same problem. May ask you talk about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you define "tasks" within "tasks"

Tasks definitions within tasks definitions can happen if you try to include another playbook that has a tasks definition in it.